# What is the plot of Jackson Curtis' "Farewell Atlantis"?

Tags: movie, 2012

In 2012, Jackson Curtis is the author of Farewell Atlantis, a [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=3MoTRijXNbwC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0) which Adrian Hemsley has read up to around day 300 when the shuttle (Atlantis) lost communication with earth.

**What is the plot of the book?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### This book doesn't exist.

Nick Sagan wrote [the foreword](http://nicksaganprojects.com/works-2/forewords/) for this wholly *fictional* novel (fictional in the sense that **the novel doesn't exist** and that **only the foreword and  the first chapter were ever actually written** as part of a viral marketing campaign for the film 2012).

He described it thusly;

> Curtis’s epic novel blends equal parts classic thriller and
>   provocative spiritual speculation. Full of larger-than-life characters
>   whose growth over the course of the novel interweave seamless with the
>   plot and a sharp, witty edge of humor, Farewell Atlantis is an
>   action-packed novel that intrigues philosophers and scientists alike.
>   This highly acclaimed first novel is splendid entertainment and
>   refreshingly forthright.
>
> Farewell Atlantis is a large sprawling tale of conspiracy, politics
>   and ideology. With his thorough research and lucid writing style,
>   Curtis explores the apocalyptic realm through the complementary lens
>   of science and art, and presents a bold exploration of the human
>   spirit. The novel aims to educate readers on reclaiming their
>   birthright as owners of the planet rather than victims or subjects to
>   the political, education and economic machinery while awakening them
>   to a higher global evolution of consciousness.
>
> As the story unfolds, Curtis delves into the lost knowledge of the
>   ‘ancient ones,’ sacred sites, shamans and interdimensional worlds. He
>   blends the events of many years throughout history with the events of
>   today and the conspiracy theories into a story of tomorrow. An
>   intricate plot, skilled narrative technique and well developed
>   characters make this a novel most readers will find absorbing and
>   comprehensible.

You can read Chapter One online [here](https://www.facebook.com/farewellatlantisjacksoncurtis/posts/215762995217642) on the 2012 film viral page on facebook